# PHP - Problems running ffmpeg.exe with shell_exec on Windows

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg, flv, mp4

I am trying to encode an FLV file to MP4 with ffmpeg.exe, its all working fine when running the code on the commandprompt (I have tried simply echoing the command and pasting it into the cmdline)

Note: Using windows.

Here is the code:
it does not return anything, and does not encode anything, there are no errors, nothing happens :(, `system($cmd, $returnval)` returns `1` that's all
running commands like `dir` works fine, so I have the required access.

```
<?php
$title = $_GET['file'];
// encoding command > , below shows info "flv/'.$title.'.flv" "mp4/'.$title.'.mp4"
$cmd = ('cd C:/inetpub/wwwroot/run/ && ffmpeg.exe -i "flv/'.$title.'.flv"');
$ll = system($cmd, $fv);
echo "CMD: $cmd \nFull output: $fv \nLL = $ll";
?>
```

ffmpeg.exe -h will return the help text, I am starting to wonder if it could have something to do with the other outputs having colours in them?

Any ideas? :O

(The cd is not the problem because `$cmd = ('cd C:/inetpub/wwwroot/run/ && ffmpeg.exe -h');` works fine, its actually already in that directory)

Comment: IIS is notoriously a PITA with commands line operations from PHP that access the filesystem because of some really messed up Windows permissions. Try running the PHP script from the command line: odds are, it will work. If it does, then you'll need to verify the permissions for the application pool account your site is running under.

Comment: I don't think I have running of php scripts via cmd setup, I'm using IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012

Comment: @Lusitanian , you were right, i had to allow the IIS user specically to access the .exe file, I guess `-h` worked because its a help command, also would be nice if you could put that into an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: glad it worked -- created an answer for you to accept -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give IIS permissions to access `ffmpeg.exe`. IIS permissions with PHP are a PITA (this is an answer so you can accept it per comment).

Comment: If you had read the other answers you would see it has been determined that other commands DO work. This is not a permission issue.

Comment: @L0j1k Except that you're wrong......read the comments...he told me to write this as an answer so he could accept it.

Comment: So he lied then when he told me that the PHP worked with both dir and ffmpeg. Read through the comments. You can see very plainly where this King person said he tried it and it worked. I can't help it if I am lied to about results.

Comment: @L0j1k You weren't lied to --- it's how IIS works. It's a complete PITA to deal with with permissions which I know from unfortunate firsthand experience. I've never quite figured out exactly what its criteria are but I've run into this exact issue running imagick.